# selected text background color for Visual Studio Code quick search (ctrl+f) input

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've searched for this setting for a while now, but just can't find it. How can I change the background color of selected text in the search box? Here is an example - as you can see (or not), foo is selected. I'd like to change the background color of that selection.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Oddly, it is just

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "selection.background": "#ff0000",
}
```

Stumbled on it at [theme base colors](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#base-colors):

> `selection.background`: Background color of text selections in the
> workbench (for input fields or text areas, does not apply to
> selections within the editor and the terminal).